# Groovy split() method bug?

Tags: string, groovy

The following Groovy snippet produces weird results to me :

```
def s = "123456"
assert s.split("").size() == s.size()
```

Results in :

```
Assertion failed: 

assert s.split("").size() == s.size()
       | |         |      |  | |
       | |         7      |  | 6
       | |                |  123456
       | |                false
       | [, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
       123456
```

Is there something I've missed on the split() method behaviour or is this a real bug ?

Comment: I'm using the latest Groovy build (1.7.5)

Comment: That's exactly the same behavior as you'd expect from Java

Comment: @tim_yates: yup, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Groovy, but I'm going to go out on a limb here, and guess that `String.split()` works the same way as it does in Java. This means that the argument you're passing to `split()` is a String which represents a regex - in this case, the empty string. As per [the Java docs](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument [split](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%2C%20int%29) method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

This means that your call `split("")` (e.g. "split on the empty string") is equivalent to `split("", 0)`. Every (non-empty) string starts *and* ends with the empty string. So, your `split("")` call is in fact giving you `[, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ]`, *less the trailing empty strings*, hence, `[, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. That's indeed what I was missing here.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using split()? Use toCharArray():

```
assert s.toCharArray().length == s.size()
```